# Debug: How can i look at my browsers output?

Tags: c#, packet-capture

I have this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688464/ajax-request-from-net-give-me-unexpected-results

and i am using tamper data but i am sure firefox is formatting the data in ways i dont understand. Is there a tool i can use to check firefox post request? and perhaps my C# post request?

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you download the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox, this will allow you to debug on the browser side more easily.

Also take a look at [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (or similar) to inspect the HTTP requests that are actually going out onto the network.

Comment: I can't recommend firebug highly enough.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/) is a widely used web proxy/debugger - you can easily see incoming and outgoing requests with it. It can be used with all browsers.